# CreatedBy is now the group email

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a job that picks up ownership from the CreatedBy property on sites. This has stopped working as we can se CreatedBy now is the email created with the group. Is there anyway to get the email of the person creating the site from csom?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the author porperty. Below CSOM powershell script for your reference:

```
$webUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/michael"
$UserName="michael"
$Password ="password"
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext $webUrl
$context.Credentials = $Credentials
$web = $context.Web
$author=$web.author
$context.Load($author)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$author.email
```

Comment: Sorry you cant see that. But createdby in the DB is author. I think it is when you create teams sites then the email of the group is used instead of the person creating the site.

Comment: If so, I don't think it's possible to get the person creating the site.